# AutoMapper One-To-Many Filter and ProjectTo

Tags: automapper

I have the below two Entities (one-to-many)

```
public class ApplicationCode
{
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string? ApplicationAcrynom { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationIndex { get; set; }
    public IList<ApplicationCodeTranslation> ApplicationCodeTranslations { get; private set; } = new List<ApplicationCodeTranslation>();
}

public class ApplicationCodeTranslation
{
    public Guid ApplicationCodeTranslationId { get; set; }
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Guid LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string? ApplicationDescription { get; set; }
    public ApplicationCode ApplicationCode { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The goal is to populate the below Dto where I need to filter one language from the child list (IList ApplicationCodeTranslations) in the ApplicationCode entity to get the description value

```
public class ApplicationCodeDto : IMapFrom<ApplicationCode>
{
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string? ApplicationAcrynom { get; set; }
    public string? ApplicationDescription { get; set; }

    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
    {
        profile.CreateMap<ApplicationCode, ApplicationCodeDto>();
        profile.CreateMap<ApplicationCodeTranslation, ApplicationCodeDto>();
    }
}
```

I tried below, but it does not give the intended result.

It omits the ApplicationDescription (gives null), the whole **.Include** line is not translated to SQL at all.

```
    var test1 = await _context.ApplicationCodes
        .Include(e => e.ApplicationCodeTranslations.Where(l => l.LanguageId == _languageId))
        .ProjectTo<ApplicationCodeDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .ToListAsync();
```

The other option I tried is

```
var test2 = await _context.ApplicationCodes
    .SelectMany(e => e.ApplicationCodeTranslations)
    .Where(l => l.LanguageId == _languageId)
    .ProjectTo<ApplicationCodeDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Which omits the properties of the CodeApplication and brings only the child list properties, as SelectMany only brings back the props of the child.

The only way I managed to make it work is below:

```
var test3 = await _context.ApplicationCodes
    .SelectMany(e => e.ApplicationCodeTranslations.Where(l => l.LanguageId == _languageId), 
    (a,t) => new ApplicationCodeDto{
        ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId,
        ApplicationAcrynom = a.ApplicationAcrynom,
        ApplicationDescription = t.ApplicationDescription,
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

How can AutoMapper (v.11) help in this scenario to avoid mapping the DTO props manually?
Does ProjectTo work here?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/3713#discussioncomment-1141771

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, many thanks for flagging this, but unfortunately it does not help. ProjectTo alone does not bring the child entity.

Comment: Of course it does :) `ProjectTo` is just a `Select` statement, so `Include` is useless. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). You're obviously missing smth.

Comment: "Of course it does :)" how? If ProjectTo is just a Select stmt then why we use include in select stmt to fetch relational entities? and why include is useless in ProjectTo. Execution plans shows only the props of the parent entity is mapped and nothing from the child enity

Comment: You select smth from the child entity, you don't use Include. But you really need to spend some time to better understand how ef linq queries work.